# Is Garbage Collection occurring on my static property before my background worker has fully consumed it?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, garbage-collection

I have a background worker in a web page which processes a large file import.  I have a static property containing a Dictionary of values which I need my background worker to access.  To prevent issues with garbage collection, I stringify the Dictionary when passing it into the background worker.  The problem is, 1 out of 20 or so times, the Dictionary appears to be garbage collected **before** it is stringified.

```
static readonly Dictionary<int, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

// When button is clicked, I fire the background worker

// Assume for posterity, I've filled the Dictionary with a list of values and those values exist at the time the worker is queued up.

```
protected void OnProcessClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessInBackground, new object[] { 
        DictionaryIntIntToCsv(myDictionary)
        });
}
```

// Example of the Background Process

```
private void ProcessInBackground(object state)
{
    object[] parms = state as object[];
    if (parms != null && parms.Length > 0)
    {
        var MyNewDictionary = DictionaryIntIntFromCsv(parms[0] as string);
        //... Doing something with the Dictionary
    }

}
```

// Here are some helper methods I am using to stringify the Dictionary.  You can ignore these unless you think they have something to do with the issue at hand.

```
public static Dictionary<int, int> DictionaryIntIntFromCsv(string csv)
{
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        foreach (var pair in csv.Split(','))
        {
            var arrNameValue = pair.Split(':');

            if (arrNameValue.Count() != 2) continue;

            var key = 0;
            var val = 0;

            int.TryParse(arrNameValue[0], out key);
            int.TryParse(arrNameValue[1], out val);

            if (key > 0 && val > 0)
            {
                dictionary.Add(key, val);
            }
        }

        return dictionary;
}

public static string DictionaryIntIntToCsv(Dictionary<int, int> dictionary)
{
        var str = "";

        foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys)
        {
            var value = 0;
            dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);

            if (key == 0 || value == 0) continue;

            var item = key + ":" + value;
            str += (item + ",");
        }

        return str;
}
```

I know there is an issue with Garbage Collection.  My theory is sometimes the main thread completes and garbage collection is run before the background worker has a chance to stringify the Dictionary.  Would I be correct in assuming I could avoid issues with Garbage Collection if I stringify the Dictionary before queuing the background worker?  Like so:

```
protected void OnProcessClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var MyString = DictionaryIntIntToCsv(MyDictionary);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessInBackground, new object[] { 
        MyString
        });
}
```

NOTE:  The page is interactive and does several postbacks before firing off the background worker.

Comment: `var MyNewDictionary = DictionaryIntIntFromCsv(parms[0] as string);` Did you mean to have the keyword `var` there?

Comment: You don't seem to understand how GC works... For instance, the GC won't ever collect objects referenced by static fields. Why do you suppose the dictionary is collected?

Comment: static fields are generated before the first time they accessed and live there in memory until application ends.

Comment: "The problem is, 1 out of 20 or so times, the Dictionary appears to be garbage collected before it is stringified." Did you get a null reference exception?  What does "appears to be garbage collected"? What symptoms did you see?  As long as you have a reference to it, it shouldn't be GC'd.  Please describe in more detail what symptoms you saw and the problem.

Comment: My understanding is garbage collection can dispose of a static member in an open application if it believes there are no more references to the object in the code.  Like when it reaches the end of its process.

Comment: Objects referenced by static members will **only** be finalized when the AppDomain is unloaded (and only if you didn't call something like `Environment.FailFast`).

Comment: My server is ending the response almost immediately after initializing the background worker.  So, it is a prime opportunity for a race condition.

Comment: Also, to note.  I do not have any symptoms of premature garbage collecting in my test environment.  This only occurs when deployed to a Server 2008 environment.  I think garbage collection is more aggressive there.

Comment: The real problem here is that a thread that was started during processing of the request is left running after the request is done. You're yanking the rug out from under your background thread. This can only end badly. That you're able to hack around the problem is a little unfortunate, because it's going to encourage you to continue this terrible practice. When the server returns a response, processing of that request is *done*. Leaving an orphaned thread around is going to cause you trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely initializing the property on page load.  The reference to the property is tied to the instance of the page which existed on page load.  After the server delivered the initial page to you, the class was eligible for garbage collection.

I believe you are seeing a race condition between how long it takes the user to do the postback on the page and how long it takes the server to collect the first instance of the class.

If the property were non-static, the values would not be there on postback.  However, since it is a static property, it will exist in memory until the Garbage collector cleans it up.

Answer (score 1):

There is really a lot of misinformation and bizarre implementation in this question, so much so that it cannot actually be answered without further clarification.

What leads you to believe the dictionary will be collected once you've "stringified" it? What are you actually doing with the dictionary values in the `ProcessInBackground()` method? Is the processing actually more expensive than serializing and deserializing a dictionary to and from a `string` for no reason? If so, why is there a background worker being used at all? Why is the string passed in inside an object array instead of simply the string itself? Further on that point, why is the dictionary being serialized at all, is there any good reason can't it be passed in as the `state` argument directly?

Comment: It is a requirement to lose all references to the static Dictionary when the background worker runs.  The user could queue up another instance of the page and begin a new file import.  At which point, the static Dictionary would be replaced by a new one with different values.  I've tested this.  Also, the static Dictionary object is almost always garbage collected before the background worker completes.  I've tested this.  So, I must have a new object by value when starting the background worker.  The object array is there because my code passes in many other properties as well.

Comment: Also, it is not the stringified Dictionary being Garbage Collected.  The issue is a race condition where 1/20 times or so the static Dictionary is Garbage Collected before it is able to be stringified.  The page Response seems to be closing before the background worker gets going.

Answer (score -1):

Here you create a local variable with the dictionary:

```
if (parms != null && parms.Length > 0)
{
    var MyNewDictionary = DictionaryIntIntFromCsv(parms[0] as string);
}
```

The above does not affect the below in any way.  No where else in your code do you ever populate the static field `MyDictionary`.

**The above local variable is completely separate from the below static field you have here, so the above assignment does not affect the below property in any way:**

```
static readonly Dictionary<int, int> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

Comment: This was not an answer.  More of a grilling, really.

Comment: I pointed out a critical flaw where you assigned to a local variable instead of to the field. That local variable goes out of scope immediately.  As far as I can tell based on the description you gave, this would be a bug.

Comment: And as for the note at the end, I was trying to explain how you should describe your problem so that you may get better help.  It was in the interest of helping, not grilling. If I wasn't interested in helping I wouldn't have wasted my time.  Take how you want though and see how quickly people give up on helping you.

Comment: @user2733283 Myself and 2 others have tried to tell you that the property reference will not be garbage collected so long as you have a reference to it. You keep describing your problem in terms of a conclusion you have already formed, and not describe the problem in terms of symptoms. It's a red herring.

Comment: It's not a flaw.  You are looking for context and I deliberately left it out to simplify the post.  You would be right to point out flaws in a comment below my post.  However, you posted your comments as an answer.

Comment: Someone says "I have a problem" then the answer to that problem is to resolve the bug.  It's been fine for hundreds of other questions.

Comment: @user2733283 **no where do you assign anything to the property `MyDictionary` so how are we supposed to determine why it's not populated when you don't show a single line of code that populates it?**  Sure you didn't show some context, but with what you have there is no way we can determine the cause of your issue.  Again, describing the problem in terms of a premature conclusion is a red herring.